# Non-iterative solution to the intersection of 2 Ellipses, under constraints

Tags: geometry, intersection

I need to draw a paramaterised crescent using graphics primitives. I've looked at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032698/calculate-intersection-of-two-ellipses) but I'm hoping my problem with tighter constraints is solvable.

There are 2 intersecting ellipses with their centres on the X axis:
[image]

with the constraints:

1. A, B, C, D and L are known
2. The elllipses do intersect: A/2 + C/2 > L
3. The axes A and C are on the X axis
4. The axes B and D are parallel to the Y axis

Is there a direct, **non-iterative** solution to find X,Y?

I realise this is more Math than programming, but I'm looking for code (C, C#, VB, ...) not algebra, and I feel there's a wider audience here.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is. Form the equations of the two ellipses in the usual form, equate the two expressions that are both equal to `1`, manipulate to get `y^2` in terms of `x`, substitute that back into the expression of one of the ellipses to get a quadratic in `x`, solve. But none of this is programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it indeed cannot be done